# problems creating virtualenv when installing two different versions of Python

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyscripter

I have installed Python 2.7, pip and virtualenv on my computer and I have created a virtual environment with this same version of Python. I installed some packages in this new virtual environment too.

Later, I decided to install Python 3.6 on the same computer to create a virtual environment that works with version 3.6. I downloaded Python 3.6 and installed it by selecting Add Python 3.6 to PATH and Install for All users and I selected the option to automatically install pip. As I had previously installed virtualenv, I have not had to reinstall it. Should I?

The problem is that, once installed, when creating a virtual environment I've got an error.

As I already had a version of Python installed I have specified that I want to use Python 3.6 in the virtual environment that I am creating:
virtualenv env2_py36 -p c: \ Python36 \ python.exe

The error already says that this usually happens when you install more than one version of Python on the same computer and warns that it is necessary to check the option Install for All Users to work (as I did) and also recommends placing the appropiate PythonXX.dll file in the Scripts folder of the virtual environment. However, I see that there is already a python36.dll file there.

[image]

Could anybody tell me what should I do to fix this problem?

On the other hand, I had previously created another virtual environment using Python 2.7. I use PyScripter to run my scripts but I don't know how to connect PyScripter to my virtual environment. It's still connected to the Python2.7's system installation.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
virtualenv --python=python3.6 yourenvname
```

(3.6 is the current latest version of Python, but you can use whichever version you'd like.)